# Lambda .Where() expression to return selected/flagged objects

Tags: c#, linq

In our software we enable certain features based on the existence of a flag.  The `Flags` class is a static class used to determine the existence of such a flag.

I came across one piece of logic that I wrote that I feel could benefit from refactoring.  The boolean logic works, but I think it's difficult to understand or read because it relies very heavily on short-circuiting.

The basic logic is:

1. Get all menu items.
2. Return a subset of those menu items by using the following rule:

   - Some menu items are tied to a specific flag that is expected to be hard-coded in some way.  The menu item name may not match the associated flag.
   - Any other menu items should be displayed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
private IEnumerable<MenuItemDefinition> GetMenuItems()
{
     return GetAllMenuItems().Where(mi => 
          (mi.MethodName != "NewWidget" || Flags.HasFlag("Feature1")) &&
          (mi.MethodName != "NewDongle" || Flags.HasFlag("Feature2")));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you control the MenuItemDefinition class, why not just add a feature tag to it?

```
public class MenuItemDefinition
{
    public string MethodName { get; set; }
    public string Feature { get; set; }
}

// each instance
new MenuItemDefinition { MethodName = "NewWidget", Feature = "Widgets" }

// GetMenuItems():
return GetAllMenuItems().Where(m => FeatureIsEnabled(m.Feature));
```

If not, you could put them in a dictionary:

```
var items = new Dictionary<string, MenuItemDefinition[]> {
    { "Widgets", new[] {
        new MenuItemDefinition { MethodName = "NewWidget" },
        new MenuItemDefinition { MethodName = "DeleteWidget" }
    },
    { "Default", new[] {
        // ....
    }
}

return items.Where(pair => FeatureIsEnabled(pair.Key)).SelectMany(pair => pair.Value);
```

Or better yet, build the initial list based upon content in a dictionary. That way you don't run the risk of having typos in the switch or the initial setup:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string[]> 
{
    { "Widgets", new[] { "NewWidget", "DeleteWidget" },
    { "Default", new[] { "..." }
    ...
}

var menuItems = dict
    .Where(p => FeatureIsEnabled(p.Key))
    .SelectMany(p => p.Value)
    .Select(mn => new MenuItemDefinition { MethodName = mn });

// GetMenuItems()
return menuItems; // :)
```

Comment: Hi @Lars-Erik, thanks for the answer.  I've provided additional information in the example that answers your question, I hope that is helpful.

Comment: I got it, entirely new answer. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the updated response.  I'm not able to make changes to the MenuItemDefinition class, but if I were able to, this would be the best solution.  For reference, I've posted my solution separately as well.

Comment: Oh no, not the switch! It's evil. ;)
At least pull it out and hide it in a method as I first described.
Anyway, I added a third proposal, which I hope appeals.

Comment: Ah yes, switch is very evil indeed!  The GetMenuItems() method is in fact the method that hides the implementation so we are already in a hidden place for such evil things.   That being said, I like the dictionary approach even more!